# jquery attr is not working to disable a dropdown

Tags: jquery

This is my current script.
The `else if` is not working.

```
$('#groupbyCheckbox').change(function() {
  if ($( "#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled", true )) {
    $("#groupbyDropdown").attr('disabled','');
    alert('true');
  }
  else if ($( "#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled", false )) {
    alert();
    $("#groupbyDropdown").attr('disabled','disabled');
    alert('false');
  }
});

additional question.

$('#newCheckBox').change(function(){
        $("#dropDown").empty();
        var items = [];
        $.each(var1, function(key, data) {
            items.push('<option value='+key+'>'+varlist+'</option>');
        });
        $("#dropDown").append(items.join(''));
    });
```

Comment: you need to use `$("#groupbyDropdown").prop('disabled',true);`

Comment: pass argument to second alert

Comment: the 1st if is working but the 2nd is not.

Comment: the alert is always true

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/xq0kt3kk/23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you're setting the value instead of getting it. See here:

```
if ($( "#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled", true )) {
```

actually sets the attribute. What you want is to check it's current value:

```
if ($( "#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled" ) == true) {
```

or simply:

```
if ($( "#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled" )) {
```

The same principle applies for the `else if`:

```
else if ($( "#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled", false )) {
```

should be:

```
else if ($( "#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled" ) == false) {
```

or simply:

```
else if (!$( "#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled" )) {
```

---

That's why it never enters the else-block - you always set it to true beforehand (and the whole condition in both `if` and `else if` will evaluate to true anyway so there's no real checking taking place).

See a simple example here (toggling the checkbox disabled state): http://jsfiddle.net/Lohervar/

Comment: it's still always true

Comment: Nope, see the example I wrote.

Comment: what if I will use this in drop down?

Comment: i edit my question and add some code I want to empty the select if the user uncheck the the checkbox.

Comment: Empty as in delete all the options or just unselect the selected one? (btw. you should probably write it as a new question)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is to enable/disable the select based on whether the checkbox is checked

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#groupbyCheckbox').change(function() {
    $("#groupbyDropdown").prop('disabled', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="groupbyCheckbox" />
<select id="groupbyDropdown">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

---

In your code there are multiple problems,

- In the `if` condition you are using the setter version of `.prop()` which will always return a jquery object, thus will always be truthy
- Also should not use .attr() to set properties like disabled, you need to use .prop()

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#groupbyCheckbox').change(function() {
   var isDisable= $("#groupbyDropdown" ).prop("disabled");
   $("#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled",!isDisable);
});
```

NOTE: It is setting disable property $( "#groupbyDropdown" ).prop( "disabled", true ), not return `Boolean` ,it always return `object`

use  `if($("#groupbyDropdown" ).prop("disabled")==false)`

Comment: @Shomz for what ? That is does not meter who post the first or last ans ,

Comment: I just did, and yes, it matters if the two answers are almost identical because it's obvious which one is stolen. Otherwise nothing could stop me from claiming that I've invented electricity...

Comment: @Shomz This is common  syntax ,how can  you told me it is copy

Comment: @Shomz Oh Great !!!! In the world You only know the jquery ,i think you invented jquery Framework

Comment: My point exactly. Btw. I don't like jQuery and thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Shomz WC , That is newton's third law :)